# error: invalid conversion from

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linked-list

So I have a node class:

```
template <typename Type>
class NodeType
{
    public:
    Type m_data;
    NodeType<Type> *mp_next;
    // note data goes uninitialized for default constructor
    // concept being Type's constructor would auto-init it for us
    NodeType() { mp_next = NULL; }
    NodeType(Type data) {m_data = data; mp_next = NULL;}
};
```

And I'm trying to make a new node like this:

```
NodeType<int> n1 = new NodeType<int>(5);
```

And the compiler is telling me:

```
SLTester.cpp:73:40: error: invalid conversion from ‘NodeType<int>*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
SingList.h:29:2: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘NodeType<Type>::NodeType(Type) [with Type = int]’ [-fpermissive]
```

Can anyone help me figure out as to why this is happening and/or what am I actually supposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By defining `NodeType<int> n1`, `n1` is not a pointer type,

update:

```
NodeType<int> n1 = new NodeType<int>(5);
```

to:

```
NodeType<int> n1{5};
```

Or

```
NodeType<int> n1(5);
```